# Why does my labels move when I expand my TableViewCell and why do I get different cell animation when tapped?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I made expandable `tableViewCell` which expands and collapses when tapped, I also have two labels in my cell (`dateLabel` & `textLabel`) but when I tap the cell both my labels move with it too. How do I make them static and stop them from moving when tapped.

Here is my code of class which has the `tableView`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
 selectedIndexPath = nil
 } else {
 selectedIndexPath = indexPath
 }

 var indexPaths : Array<IndexPath> = []
 if let previous = previousIndexPath {
 indexPaths += [previous]
 }
 if let current = selectedIndexPath {
 indexPaths += [current]
 }
 if indexPaths.count > 0 {
 tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
 }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellID") as! CustomCell
    cell.textLabel?.text=list[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateLabel?.text = time.indices.contains(indexPath.row) ? time[indexPath.row] : "Not Available"
    print(time.indices.contains(indexPath.row))
    return (cell)
} 
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        return CustomCell.expandedHeight
    } else {
        return CustomCell.defaultHeight
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as! CustomCell).watchFrameChanges()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as! CustomCell).ignoreFrameChanges()
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [CustomCell] {
        cell.ignoreFrameChanges()
    }
}
```

and my `CustomCell` class :

```
var isObserving = false;

class var expandedHeight: CGFloat { get { return 170 } }
class var defaultHeight: CGFloat  { get { return 40 } }

func checkHeight() {
    textView.isHidden = (frame.size.height < CustomCell.expandedHeight)
}


func watchFrameChanges() {
    if !isObserving {
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.initial], context: nil)
        isObserving = true;
    }
}

func ignoreFrameChanges() {
    if isObserving {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
        isObserving = false;
    }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "frame" {
        checkHeight()
    }
}
```

**I also get the different animations for different cells..like I get slide animation for 1st cell and fade for rest of all**

Comment: Can you provide info/code about how you layout the `cell.textLabel` and `cell.dataLabel`? You are using code to layout? (seems not) or storyboard with Auto layout constraints?

Comment: @PangHoMing I'm not using any constraints..on either of the labels. The `dateLabel` is on the stroyboard but the `textLabel` is called programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @PangHoMing I'm not using any constraints..on either of the labels.
>   The dateLabel is on the stroyboard but the textLabel is called
>   programmatically.

so I think thats the problem. For example, the default `textLabel` comes with the cell always layout horizontally centre. And for the `dateLabel` case, you need to set constraints inside the storyboard.

Otherwise iOS Autolayout will layout the views in 'his' way.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Quick advices:

Avoid using the `cell.textLabel` comes with default cell
You can either layout the cell programmatically by implementing `layoutSubView` in your custom cell class. But if you do not comfort with layout the UI using code, the best way of doing this is to use Storyboard.

Take a look of these will help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo

https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is your layout issue.If you want your label to be static then you will have to give constraints according to your this need only.Like if you want tha label to be at tha same position even if Expand button is pressed  then give your label constraint - leading top height width.Thats it and the frame will be same throghout.

Comment: yes I've managed to do that but what about my other question regarding `UITableViewRowAnimation`? I get 2 animations

Comment: So you are getting two animations by default?

Comment: yes when I use `UITableViewRowAnimation.default` my first cell has a fade animation while all my other cells have slide animation.

Comment: Can you pass nil here?

Comment: I can pass none but that gives abrupt effect. I want slide animation in all of my cells.

Comment: passing .none should worlk according to me.

Comment: it gives `.none` animation to my last added cell and slide to remaining.